# android realm predefined database performance

Tags: android, realm

I have 6236 rows with Arabic character I used predefined database and load it successfully here is the code for read the file

```
  private String copyBundledRealmFile(InputStream inputStream, String outFileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), outFileName);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and make configure for realm here

```
       copyBundledRealmFile(SplashScreen.this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tests), "test");


            RealmConfiguration config1 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(SplashScreen.this)
                .name("test")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config1);
```

and make check to read and  copy realm one time

but problem loading the data take about 5 seconds every time the app open to make the configure and have instance of realm

here is the code of realm instance

```
    private static MyReleam instance;
private final Realm realm;

public MyReleam(Application application) {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}

public static MyReleam with(Fragment fragment) {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyReleam(fragment.getActivity().getApplication());
    }
    return instance;
}

public static MyReleam with(Activity activity) {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyReleam(activity.getApplication());
    }
    return instance;
}

public static MyReleam with(Application application) {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyReleam(application);
    }
    return instance;
}

public Realm getRealm() {

    return realm;
}
```

and use it here

```
 this.realm = MyReleam.with(this).getRealm();
```

how can I optimize using it and decrease time of loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for answer of EpicPandaForce I use documentation as https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html
the I was conflict in asset pass it was only the name of files in asset

```
RealmConfiguration config1 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(SplashScreen.this).assetFile(SplashScreen.this,"tests")//name of files in assets (test)
                .name("test")
                .schemaVersion(1).migration(new Migration())
                .build();

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config1);
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) Use `initialData()` or `assetFile()` (preferably `assetFile()`) instead of populating in a migration

2.) *Forget everything* you've read [in this tutorial](http://androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/) because it's an outdated mess (I can tell that's where the `MyReleam` is from) and refer to [my article](http://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149) instead

Comment: in documentation they said that:                                                  WARNING: This could potentially be a lengthy operation and should ideally be done on a background thread.

Comment: Which one? I found nothing.

Comment: about the assestFile()    https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html

Comment: ...well technically it's a file i/o operation from your assets to the internal storage folder. But it executes on the thread that first opens the Realm. If your Realm is set up with initial data, then you spare the migration.

Comment: thanks as I understand after I copy the file I get the path and then use it in           RealmConfiguration config1 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(SplashScreen.this).assetFile(SplashScreen.this,path)
                    .name("test")
                    .schemaVersion(1)
                    .build();
            Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config1);

Comment: um. You don't need to do manual copying, `assetFile()` should be able to handle it

Comment: I am sorry but how can it handle it can you provide me with example of code and thanks

Comment: I try this but give me error here is the code                 RealmConfiguration conf = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(SplashScreen.this)
                    .initialData(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {

                            realm.createObject(InfoTafseer.class);
                            realm.commitTransaction();
                        }
                    }).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().name("test").build();
             Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(conf);

Comment: and use the realm object as    your article                                                                   Realm realm = null;
        try { // I could use try-with-resources here
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(infoTafseerArrayList);
                }
            });
        } finally {
            if(realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }

Comment: give me error java.lang.NullPointerException: No default RealmConfiguration was found. Call setDefaultConfiguration() first

Comment: You don't need to close the Realm and you don't need to commit the transaction in `initialData()`